# Shell script to validate a csv file column by column

Tags: shell, csv, scripting

I was wondering how I would go about writing this in shell? I want to validate a field in a csv file coulmn by coulmn. For example  only want to validate if coulmn number one is number

```
Number,Letter

1,u
2,h
3,d
4,j
```

above

```
Loop - for all files (loop1)

 loop  from rows(2-n) (loop2) #skipping first row since its a header

     validate column 1

     validate column 2

     ...

     end loop2
           if( file pass validation)
               copy to goodFile directory
           else(
                send to badFile directory


 end loop1
```

What I have here below is a row by row validation, what modification would i need to make it like the above psuedo code i have above. I am terrible at unix just started learning about awk.

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in /source/*.csv

 do
   awk -F"," '{                       # awk -F", " {'print$2'} to get the     fields.
$date_regex = '~(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d~';

if (length($1) == "")  
    break
if (length($2) == "") && (length($2) > 30)
    break
if (length($3) == "") && ($3 !~ /$date_regex/)
    break
if (length($4) == "") && (($4 != "S") || ($4 != "E")   
    break
if (length($5) == "") && ((length($5) < 9 || (length($5) > 11)))
    break



}' file

   #whatever you need with "$file"
```

done

Comment: Is there some particular reason this needs to be done as a shell script rather than in some other language? If you're better at python or perl or something you could script it in that.

Comment: have to implement it in shell sadly :/

Comment: I don't see how these sort of statements can ever execute ... `if (length($5) == "") && ((length($5) < 9 ...` length should return 0 or a positive number right?  Yes, `== ""` will probably be true when lenth=0, but then why bother testing if  `length($5) <9` ? Also an assignment like `$date_regex=... ` No `$` on LHS variable names  for assignments. And why `break`, why not `printf ("error on line %s, for col#=%d, value=%s', NR, 5, $5)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will combine two different ways to write a loop.
Lines starting with # are comment:

```
# Read all files. I hope no file have spaces in their names
for file in /source/*.csv ; do
   # init two variables before processing a new file
   FILESTATUS=GOOD
   FIRSTROW=true
   # process file 1 line a time, splitting the line by the 
   # Internal Field Sep ,
   cat "${file}" | while IFS=, read field1 field2; do
      # Skip first line, the header row
      if [ "${FIRSTROW}" = "true" ]; then
         FIRSTROW=FALSE
         # skip processing of this line, continue with next record
         continue;
      fi

      # Lot of different checks possible here
      # Can google them easy (check field integer)
      if [[ "${field1}" = somestringprefix*  ]]; then
         ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
         # Stop inner loop
         break
      fi
      somecheckonField2
   done
   if [ ${FILESTATUS} = "GOOD" ] ; then
      mv ${file} /source/good
   else
      mv ${file} /source/bad
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no stray whitespace in the file, here's how I'd do it in bash.

```
# validate: first field is an integer
# validate: 2nd field is a lower-case letter

for file in *.csv; do
    good=true
    while IFS=, read -ra fields; do
        if [[ ! ( 
                  ${fields[0]} =~ ^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$
                  && ${fields[1]} == [a-z]
                ) ]]
        then
            good=false
            break
        fi
    done < "$file"
    if $good; then
        : # handle good file
    else
        : # handle bad file
    fi
done
```